# Как выбрать из таблицы с помощью HQL уникальные по одному параметру?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

Как выбрать из таблицы с помощью HQL уникальные по одному параметру
[image: Table feed]

Я написал запрос, но запрос не возвращает уникальных значений, но дает все строки, содержащие повторяющиеся строки с тем же ref_id. Итак, select работает неправильно

[image: Результат ожидаемый]

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM FeedEntity o WHERE o.referenceId IN (SELECT DISTINCT ol.referenceId FROM FeedEntity ol) AND o.id < :lastId")
List<FeedEntity> getByIdBefore(@Param("lastId") Long lastId, Pageable pageable);
```

Это класс, отображаемый для запроса:

```
public class FeedEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserEntity user;

@Enumerated
@Column(name = "type")
private FeedType type;

@Column(name = "ref_id")
private Long referenceId;

@Column(name = "create_time")
private Timestamp createTime;

public FeedEntity(UserEntity user, FeedType type, Long referenceId) {
    this.user = user;
    this.type = type;
    this.referenceId = referenceId;
    this.createTime = DateTimeUtil.getCurrentTimestamp();
}
}
```

Мне нужно выбрать все уникальные строки по reference_id (ref_id)

Нативный запрос в Mysql выдал правильное значение

```
SELECT * FROM feed WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(Id) FROM feed fe GROUP BY 
fe.ref_id)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот правильный запрос для выборки.

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM FeedEntity o WHERE o.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(o.id) 
FROM FeedEntity fe GROUP BY fe.referenceId)")
```

Надеюсь кому-то будет полезно

Единственное что не работает с доп условием

```
 @Query("SELECT o FROM FeedEntity o WHERE o.id < :lastId AND o.id IN (SELECT 
 DISTINCT MIN(fe.id) FROM FeedEntity fe GROUP BY fe.referenceId)")
 List<FeedEntity> getByIdBefore(@Param("lastId") Long lastId, Pageable 
 pageable);
```

Comment: DISTINCT можете смело убрать - толку от него никакого, а работы серверу больше.

Comment: `SELECT o FROM FeedEntity o WHERE ...` В секции FROM Вы определяете, что `o` - это алиас таблицы. И почему-то именно его выводите в секции SELECT, хотя в нативном запросе правильно используете звезду.

Comment: @Query("SELECT o FROM FeedEntity o WHERE o.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(o.id) FROM FeedEntity fe GROUP BY fe.referenceId)")

Comment: Да, именно в этой строке.

Comment: Спасибо поправил)

Comment: @Vit, вы вставили в вопрос ответ? Если да, то лучше напишите в ответ, просто другие пользователи будут искать и возможно пропустят это решение

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query("SELECT o FROM FeedEntity o WHERE o.id < :lastId AND o.id IN (SELECT 
 DISTINCT MIN(fe.id) FROM FeedEntity fe GROUP BY fe.referenceId)")
 List<FeedEntity> getByIdBefore(@Param("lastId") Long lastId, Pageable 
 pageable);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]